# Hiding Rows with different buttons in Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift 2, I have 2 buttons that I want each individual button to close a specific individual row in my table view.
I have the first If statement working, but my second IF statement i can't get to work, I am not sure how to implement it correctly. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var PickerMaterialViewHidden = true

var PickerPostViewHidden = true


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2 && PickerMaterialViewHidden {
        return 0
    }
    else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    if indexPath.row == 5 && PickerPostViewHidden {
        return 0
    }
    else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

}


@IBAction func ToggleMaterialPickerView(sender: AnyObject) {
    PickerMaterialViewHidden = !PickerMaterialViewHidden
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

@IBAction func TogglePostPickerView(sender: AnyObject) {
    PickerPostViewHidden = !PickerPostViewHidden
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Comment: Because the code execution will never ever reach the second if statement. There is an if/else before it, look at what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, sorry i left out that I tried the else statement as well, and it keeps saying it will never execute.

Comment: If you could show me an example that might show best way to deal with the send IF statement that would be great as well. Thanks,'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you `heightForRowAtIndexPath` try

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2 && PickerMaterialViewHidden {
        return 0
    }

    if indexPath.row == 5 && PickerPostViewHidden {
        return 0
    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

}
```

And also try changing to this for a smooth animation

```
@IBAction func ToggleMaterialPickerView(sender: AnyObject) {
    PickerMaterialViewHidden = !PickerMaterialViewHidden
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        })
}
```

Comment: Chris, Thanks so much, Works Perfectly :) Not sure whey I didn't think you could have the IF statements like that. Now I understand. Thanks for the education and your time. Cheers